# How to bind "this" for react component method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can't understand why `this.click = this.click.bind(this)` is needed and what is it doing.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                name: 'Initial State'
            };
            this.click = this.click.bind(this);
        }
        click() {
            this.setState({
                name: 'React Rocks!'
            });
        }
        render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <button onClick = {this.click}>Click Me</button>
            <h1>{this.state.name}</h1>
            </div>
        );
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you *didn't* use `bind()`, when `this.click()` was called from the event listener, the value of `this` would *not* be your React component (where `state` and `props` etc. are), but instead `this` would be the function `this.click()` itself. Normally, every time a function is called, the execution context - the value of `this` - is set to the function itself.

Of course, that's not such a good thing if you want to access the context of your React component. `bind()` is one way to ensure a function runs with the same execution context of your component, giving you access to `this.state`, `this.props` etc. inside your function. Another way is to use the ES6 arrow function declaration:

```
let foo = () => {console.log("bar")}
```

Which automatically sets the value of `this` for `foo` to whatever context the function was declared in. If you declare `foo` in the same context as your React component, it will retain that context, thus ensuring that the value of `this` is the same inside of `foo`.

Comment: I'd just like to point out something about es6 arrow functions and react... You will see a lot of examples where people declare `onClick={ () => { _function_body_ } }` inside the `render()` method. You should refrain from doing this because it will cause a performance hit by redefining the function on every render call. This is not what @jered is suggesting just btw.

Comment: Ok so if my Click() function inside its code hadn't used "this" then bind wouldn't be needed, am i right?

Comment: @Sid24 That is correct. If your function - for example - simply takes an argument and returns a result and doesn't need access to your component state, props, or functions, then you would not need to bind it.

Answer (score 3):

Accorging to [React Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html) binding is necessary because class methods are not bound by default. And if you pass a callback to an event handler without binding, 'this' will be undefined.

You can use **property initializers** to bind your callbacks:

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: 'Initial State'
        };
    }
    handleClick = () => {
        this.setState({
            name: 'React Rocks!'
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
          <div>
          <button onClick = {this.handleClick}>Click Me</button>
          <h1>{this.state.name}</h1>
          </div>
      );
    }
};
```

You can also use an **arrow function** in the callback:

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: 'Initial State'
        };
    }
    handleClick() {
        this.setState({
            name: 'React Rocks!'
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
          <div>
          <button onClick = {() => this.handleClick()}>Click Me</button>
          <h1>{this.state.name}</h1>
          </div>
      );
    }
};
```

Comment: Instead of Bind in Constructor, you can use bind in render also :                             
onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}

Answer (score 2):

You need to do it because the callback function is called with a different `context`. By performing `.bind( this )` you ensure that the function is always invoked with the same `this` `context` as your component.

Editted: per @jered's comment.

Comment: Note that you don't have to use `.bind(this)` if the function is an arrow function.

Comment: You're mostly correct, however when we're talking about `this` we're talking about _context_, not _scope_. Context and scope are different (albeit related) things but are often confused for each other, and I think it's important to keep the distinction. `bind()` does not alter the lexical scope of the resulting function, only its context.

Answer (score 1):

Without it you should get undefined when you call your `click()` function. From the react docs...

> You have to be careful about the meaning of this in JSX callbacks. In
>   JavaScript, class methods are not bound by default. If you forget to
>   bind this.handleClick and pass it to onClick, this will be undefined
>   when the function is actually called.

Check out the documentation for some more details here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html